# Conteúdo de remoção de conta obsoleto na Central de Ajuda

Tags: bug, central-de-ajuda

Este tópico presente na Central de Ajuda está com o conteúdo desatualizado e não faz mais sentido no cenário atual do site:

### [Como eu apago minha conta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

- **Antigo procedimento:** inserção de "por favor, excluam-me" no perfil e entrar em contato com o suporte solicitando a remoção.
- **Procedimento atual:** visite a página do seu perfil, navegue até a aba `Editar perfil e configurações`, na seção `CONFIGURAÇÕES DO SITE` localizada no menu lateral, clique em `Excluir perfil`.